# How to use python-can to connect the vector virtual bus

Tags: python, can-bus, xcp

How to use python-can to connect to the vector virtual bus. I ran XCPsim(the software provided by Vector to simulate XCP slave) on my computer and wanted to use a python script to connect to the XCPsim bus and use pyxcp, but I don’t know how to connect.
so, i need some help, thanks

1. how to connect to the vector virtual(python-can connect XCPsim)
2. how to use pyxcp? The documentation for this library ignores tutorials
   [https://pyxcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://stackoverflow.com)

pyxcp:[https://github.com/christoph2/pyxcp](https://stackoverflow.com)
python-can: [https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can](https://stackoverflow.com)

this is my code:

```
from pya2l.parser import A2lParser as Parser
import pyxcp
import can

with open("XCPSIM.a2l", "r") as f:
    a2l_string = f.read()

# print('a2l_string', a2l_string)
with Parser() as p:
    # get the AST.
    ast = p.tree_from_a2l(a2l_string.encode())
    # print('ast', ast)

measurements = []


for measurement in ast.PROJECT.MODULE[0].MEASUREMENT:
    measurements.append(measurement)

print('measurements', len(measurements))


with can.interface.Bus(channel=0, bustype='vector', bitrate=500000) as can_bus:
    message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x1, data=[255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], is_extended_id=False, is_fd=False)
    can_bus.send(message)
    print('message', message)
# # master = pyxcp.master('CAN', 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

ok.i can answer my question.

1. Download the Vecter Hardware Configuration
2. Edit your python code, add the app_name

   `can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', app_name='my_app', channel=0)`
3. Configration the "Vecter Hardware Configuration"
4. Add 'my_app' application with 'Application Channels Configuration'
5. Set CAN Channels with 'my_app',set Virtual CAN Bus and Channel
6. switch to run status and deploy ('Vecter Hardware Configuration')
7. run XCPsim.exe and run your python code

   ```
   with can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', app_name='my_app',channel=0) as bus:
       print('bus', bus)
       message = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x1, data=[253, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], is_extended_id=False, is_fd=False)
       res = bus.send(message)
       print('send', res)
       res_msg = bus.recv()
       print('res',res_msg)
   ```